# Регулярное выражение PHP, от а - п, и р-я отличается результат

Tags: php

Всем привет. Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Надо сделать регулярку.

Проверка: Должен быть 1 кирилический символ.

Кодировка: UTF-8

$letter = "п"; //киррилический символ

$res = preg_match('/^([а-яА-Я]{0,2})$/', $letter);

если $letter от "а" до "п", то $res == 1,
а если $letter от "р" до "я", то $res == 0.

//{0,2} - зесь "2", потому что в UTF-8 один киррилический символ воспринимается как 2 (считает по байтам).

Кто знает с чем связано такое поведение???

Comment: Модификатор `u` используйте для UTF-8

Comment: Да, помогло вот так '/^([а-яА-Я]{0,1})$/u' работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex, а буква `Ё` вам не нужна?

Comment: Блин, нужна. А как быть в таком случае? Не заметил что она не работает.